# Standardised Country codes across map APIs?

Tags: api, geolocation, maps, standards

Im using the Google maps geolocation API to get a users country and city, and then if that fails, as a fallback I'm using Maxminds Geo IP City service to get the rough location by IP address.
Both APIs have codes for countries, are these standardised throughout the map API world, for example would the UK be UK on all or GB in some? Im trying to work out whether I can relate attractions to a list of country codes as one country code to many attractions.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if every Map API would use this but it occured to me there is proabbly an ISO standard http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1
it would make logical sense for the APIs to follow such a standard.